# the map wont show up using openlayer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

i'm trying to use openlayer to display a map, but nothing is showing up, all i can see is a white page   here is my code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {

      map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");

      var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
      var  epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
      var projectTo = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

      map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-7.62300,33.59349) // Centre de la carte
      .transform(epsg4326,projectTo
      ), 12 // Zoom level
    );
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init();">
    <div id="basicMap" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define an height for your map div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
function init() {

  map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");

  var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
  var  epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
  var projectTo = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

  map.addLayer(mapnik);
  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-7.62300,33.59349).transform(epsg4326,projectTo), 12);
}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="basicMap" style="width:100%; height:100px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works but i want to know why because i have already define a height

Comment: You need to define a height in pixel not in percentage.

Comment: At the dom load, there is nothing in your div. 100% of nothing is nothing... To have a space reserved for your div, you need to fix one of the two values.